# How to imperatively handle an error, with react-query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

Being that react-query is heavily based on the **declarative** approach, the error handling I see in all examples looks something like this:

```
function Todos() {
   const { isLoading, isError, data, error } = useQuery('todos', fetchTodoList)
 
   if (isLoading) {
     return <span>Loading...</span>
   }
 
   if (isError) {//If there is an error, render different JSX
     return <span>Error: {error.message}</span>
   } 
   
   return (
     <ul>
       {data.map(todo => (
         <li key={todo.id}>{todo.title}</li>
       ))}
     </ul>
   )
 }
```

But what if I want to just show an alert, in case of an error? Or perhaps, i'm using some error handling interface, that has an imperative trigger? Something like this:

```
if (isError) alert(`An error has occurred: ${error.message}`)
```

In this case, I get  **two alerts**. Something causes the component to re-render, which of course leads to "duplicate" error handling.

Why is this important to me? Because my error handling logic might not be based on rendering some specific JSX within my component, but rather on some manual one-time trigger. The alert is just a basic example.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried using the `onError` callback?

It looks like this :

```js
    const useTodos = () =>
      useQuery(['todos'], fetchTodos, {
      // ⚠️ looks good, but is maybe _not_ what you want
      onError: (error) =>
        toast.error(`Something went wrong: ${error.message}`),
    })
```

You see, the `onError` callback on `useQuery` is called for every `Observer`, which means if you call `useTodos` twice in your application, you will get two error toasts, even though only one network request fails

Comment: This works, thank you. I have to ask though, what is the purpose of this "useTodos" custom hook?

Comment: @i.brod yeah, it's almost the same as u do,just here in the example I wrote it's an object that contain some variables, react query handles caching background updates and stale data out of the box with zero configuration

Comment: @i.brod

It is just a way to keep queries nicely organized within custom functions. In the case you have to fetch Todos in multiple places within your application, you have defined it in one place. And ofcourse its a hook hence the "use".

Comment: @i.brod By creating custom useQuery hooks you can also mock them easily within unit tests.

Comment: useQuery's onError, onSuccess, and onSettled callbacks will be deprecated in V5 so you may want to avoid this solution and instead handle the error in the component's useEffect or using the onError callback on the QueryCache. https://tkdodo.eu/blog/breaking-react-querys-api-on-purpose